# unrecognized selector sent to instance xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get an **error** when i try to run below code.

```
 @IBAction func pickAnImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PickExample.ViewController
>   pickAnImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee83c09480'
>
> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{  (Thread1:
>   signal SIGABRT)

Do i have to make a key in `info.plist`?

Comment: Have you hooked up your `pickAnImage` in XIB/storyboard?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to programming.I did not check it  before I make the question! Sorry!!